# How to automatically show an alert dialog without pressing a button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I implemented the alert dialog in the initstate() method but Init state is only called once. In my case I want the alert to appear automatically every time a variable value changes for exemple. ( I need it to suddenly pop up during using the app)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **ValueNotifier** and a **ValueListenableBuilder** so that every time the value in the **ValueNotifier** changes, the **ValueListenableBuilder** rebuilds and shows a dialog, like so:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  ValueNotifier<int> dialogTrigger = ValueNotifier(0);

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            var random = Random();
            dialogTrigger.value = random.nextInt(100);
          },
          child: const Text('Click me and change a value')
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: dialogTrigger,
          builder: (ctx, value, child) {

            Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
              showDialog(
                context: ctx,
                builder: (ctx) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('Dialog'),
                    content: Text('Hey! I got a $value'),
                  );
                });
            });
            
            return const SizedBox();
          })
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

(Again, I'm only adding a button to change the value, not to launch the dialog. That way you can programmatically change the value, which eventually launches the dialog). See if that works for your purposes.